# Difference between creating a global variable, vs one in a constructor function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If I declare a global variable x as:

```
var x = "I am window.x";
```

x will be a public property of the window object.
If I call a global function (without using "call", "apply" or attaching it to another object first), the window object will be passed in as the context (the “this” keyword).
It is like it is siting the x property on the current context, which happens to be the window.

If, however, I declare a variable in the same way inside a function, then use that function as a constructor, the property x will not be a public property of the object I just constructed (the current context).  I am happy (I know I can do this.x = …), but it just seems like a bit of a contradiction.

Have I misunderstood something (about it being a contradiction / different behaviour)?  Would anyone be able to explain what is going on, or is it just something I have to accept?

Hope that my question is clear.

Comment: "this" is not context. If you use an unqualified reference to call a function, its *this* keyword will be set to the global object, it is not "passed in". ECMA-262 defines an execution context as the scope, variables, parameters, this, and everything else that is setup when a function execution context is entered. It is a lot more than just "this" (which can be set to anything by the call).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you've understood it just fine (I pick one small nit with your terminology below). Local variables within constructor functions are just that: Local variables inside constructor functions. They're not part of the instance being initialized by the constructor function at all.

This is all a consequence of how "scope" works in JavaScript. When you call a function, an *execution context* (EC) is created for that call to the function. The EC has something called the *variable context* which has a *binding object* (let's just call it the "variable object," eh?). The variable object holds all of the `var`s and function arguments and other stuff defined within the function. This variable object is a very real thing and very important to how closures work, but you can't directly access it. Your `x` in the constructor function is a *property* of the variable object created for the call to the constructor function.

All scopes have a variable object; the magic is that the variable object for the *global* scope is the global object, which is `window` on browsers. (More accurately, `window` is a property on the variable object that refers back to the variable object, so you can reference it directly. The variable objects in function calls don't have any equivalent property.) So the `x` you define at global scope is a property of `window`.

That terminology nit-picking I promised: You've said:

> If call a global function, the window object will be passed in as the context (the “this” keyword).

Which is mostly true. E.g., if you call a global function like this:

```
myGlobalFunction();
```

...then yes, `this` will be the global object (`window`) during the call. But there are lots of other ways you might call that global function where it won't be. For instance, if you assign that "global" function to a property on an object and then call the function via that property, `this` within the call will be the object the property belongs to:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = myGlobalFunction;
obj.foo();    // `this` is `obj` within the call, not `window`
obj['foo'](); // Exactly the same as above, just different notation
```

or you might use `call` or `apply` features of function objects to set `this` explicitly:

```
var obj = {};
myGlobalFunction.call(obj, 1, 2, 3);    // Again, `this` will be `obj`
myGlobalFunction.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]); // Same (`call` and `apply` just vary
                                        // in terms of how you pass arguments
```

More to explore (disclosure: these are links to my blog, but it doesn't have ads or anything, seems unlikely I'll add them):

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html) (explores the scope chain and variable objects and such)
- [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) (more about functions and `this`)
- [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) (even more about functions and `this`)

---

**Update**: Below you've said:

> I just want to check my understanding: In any scope (global or function) there are always 2 objects: a “this” object (what is that called?) and a “variable object”. In the global scope, these 2 objects are the same. In a function’s scope, they are different, and the “variable object” is not accessible. Is that correct?

You're on the right track, and yes, there are always those two things kicking around (usually more; see below). But "scope" and `this` have **nothing** to do with each other. This is surprising if you're coming to JavaScript from other languages, but it's true. `this` in JavaScript (which is sometimes called "context" although that can be misleading) is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where the function is defined*. You set `this` when calling a function in any of several ways (see answer and links above). From a `this` perspective, there is *no difference whatsoever* between a function defined a global scope and one defined within another function. Zero. Zilch.

But yes, in JavaScript code (wherever it's defined) there's always `this`, which may be anything, and a variable object. In fact, there are frequently multiple variable objects, arranged in a chain. This is called the *scope chain*. When you try to retrieve the value of a free variable (an unqualified symbol, e.g. `x` rather than `obj.x`), the interpreter looks in the topmost variable object for a property with that name. If it doesn't find one, it goes to the next link in the chain (the next outer scope) and looks on *that* variable object. If it doesn't have one, it looks at the next link in the chain, and so on, and so on. And you know what the final link in the chain is, right? Right! The global object (`window`, on browsers).

Consider this code (assume we start in global scope; [live copy](http://jsbin.com/amavew/edit)):

```
var alpha = "I'm window.alpha";
var beta  = "I'm window.beta";

// These, of course, reference the globals above
display("[global] alpha = " + alpha);
display("[global] beta  = " + beta);

function foo(gamma) {
    var alpha = "I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `foo`";

    newSection();
    // References `alpha` on the variable object for this call to `foo`
    display("[foo] alpha = " + alpha);
    // References `beta` on `window` (the containing variable object)
    display("[foo] beta  = " + beta);
    // References `gamma` on the variable object for this call to `foo`
    display("[foo] gamma = " + gamma);

    setTimeout(callback, 200);

    function callback() {
        var alpha = "I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `callback`";

        newSection();
        // References `alpha` on the variable obj for this call to `callback`
        display("[callback] alpha = " + alpha);
        // References `beta` on `window` (the outermost variable object)
        display("[callback] beta  = " + beta);
        // References `gamma` on the containing variable object (the call to `foo` that created `callback`) 
        display("[callback] gamma = " + gamma);
    }
}

foo("I'm gamma1, passed as an argument to foo");
foo("I'm gamma2, passed as an argument to foo");

function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
function newSection() {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('hr'));
}
```

The output is this:

```
[global] alpha = I'm window.alpha
[global] beta = I'm window.beta
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[foo] alpha = I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `foo`
[foo] beta = I'm window.beta
[foo] gamma = I'm gamma1, passed as an argument to foo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[foo] alpha = I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `foo`
[foo] beta = I'm window.beta
[foo] gamma = I'm gamma2, passed as an argument to foo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[callback] alpha = I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `callback`
[callback] beta = I'm window.beta
[callback] gamma = I'm gamma1, passed as an argument to foo
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[callback] alpha = I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `callback`
[callback] beta = I'm window.beta
[callback] gamma = I'm gamma2, passed as an argument to foo
```

You can see the scope chain at work there. During a call to `callback`, the chain is (top to bottom):

- The variable object for that call to `callback`
- The variable object for the call to `foo` that created `callback`
- The global object

Note how the variable object for the call to `foo` *lives on* past the end of the `foo` function (`foo` returns before `callback` gets called by `setTimeout`). That's how closures work. When a function is created (note that a *new* `callback` function object is created each time we call `foo`), it gets an enduring reference to the variable object at the top of the scope chain as of that moment (the whole thing, not just the bits we see it reference). So for a brief moment while we're waiting our two `setTimeout` calls to happen, we have *two* variable objects for calls to `foo` in memory. Note also that arguments to functions behave exactly like `var`s. Here's the runtime of the above broken down:

1. The interpreter creates the global scope.
2. It creates the global object and populates it with its default set of properties (`window`, `Date`, `String`, and all the other "global" symbols you're used to having).
3. It creates properties on the global object for all `var` statements at global scope; initially they have the value `undefined`. So in our case, `alpha` and `beta`.
4. It creates properties on the global object for all function *declarations* at global scope; initially they have the value `undefined`. So in our case, `foo` and my utility functions `display` and `newSection`.
5. It processes each function *declaration* at global scope (in order, top to bottom):

   - Creates the function object
   - Assigns it a reference to the current variable object (the global object in this case)
   - Assigns the function object to its property on the variable object (again, the global object in this case)
6. The interpreter begins executing the step-by-step code, at the top.
7. The first line it reaches is `var alpha = "I'm window.alpha";`. It's already done the `var` aspect of this, of course, and so it processes this as a straight assignment.
8. Same for `var beta = ...`.
9. It calls `display` twice (details omitted).
10. The `foo` function declaration has already been processed and isn't part of step-by-step code execution at all, so the next line the interpreter reaches is is `foo("I'm gamma1, passed as an argument to foo");`.
11. It creates an execution context for the call to `foo`.
12. It creates a variable object for this execution context, which for convenience I'll call `foo#varobj1`.
13. It assigns `foo#varobj1` a copy of `foo`'s reference to the variable object where `foo` was created (the global object in this case); this is its link to the "scope chain."
14. The interpreter creates properties on `foo#varobj1` for all named function arguments, `var`s, and function declarations inside `foo`. So in our case, that's `gamma` (the argument), `alpha` (the `var`), and `callback` (the declared function). Initially they have the value `undefined`. (A few other default properties are created here that I won't go into.)
15. It assigns the properties for the function arguments the values passed to the function.
16. It processes each function *declaration* in `foo` (in order, beginning to end). In our case, that's `callback`:

    - Creates the function object
    - Assigns that function object a reference to the current variable object (`foo#varobj1`)
    - Assigns the function object to its property on `foo#varobj1`
17. The interpreter begins step-by-step execution of the `foo` code
18. It processes the assignment from the `var alpha = ...` line, giving `foo#varobj1.alpha` its value.
19. It looks up the free variable `newSection` and calls the function (details omitted, we'll go into detail in a moment).
20. It looks up the free variable `alpha`:

    - First it looks on `foo#varobj1`. Since `foo#varobj1` has a property with that name, it uses the value of that property.
21. It looks up `display` and calls it (details omitted).
22. It looks up the free variable `beta`:

    - First it looks on `foo#varobj1`, but `foo#varobj1` doesn't have a property with that name
    - It looks up the next link in the scope chain by querying `foo#varobj1` for its  reference to the next link
    - It looks on that next link (which happens to be the global object in this case), finds a property by that name, and uses its value
23. It calls `display`
24. It looks up `gamma` and calls `display`. This is *exactly* the same as for `alpha` above.
25. It looks up the free variable `callback`, finding it on `foo#varobj1`
26. It looks up the free variable `setTimeout`, finding it on the global object
27. It calls `setTimeout`, passing in the arguments (details omitted)
28. It returns out of `foo`. At this point, if nothing had a reference to `foo#varobj1`, that object could be reclaimed. But since the browser's timer stuff has a reference to the `callback` function object, and the `callback` function object has a reference to `foo#varobj1`, `foo#varobj1` lives on until/unless nothing refers to it anymore. This is the key to closures.
29. Wash/rinse/repeat for the second call to `foo`, which creates `foo#varobj2` and another copy of `callback`, assigning that second `callback` a reference to `foo#varobj2`, and ultimately passing that second `callback` to `setTimeout` and returning.
30. The interpreter runs out of step-by-step code to execute and goes into its event loop, waiting for something to happen
31. About 200 milliseconds go by
32. The browser's timer stuff tells the interpreter it needs to call the first `callback` function we created in `foo`
33. The interpreter creates an execution context and associated variable object (`callback#varobj1`) for the call; it assigns `callback#varobj1` a copy of the variable object reference stored on the `callback` function object (which is, of course, `foo#varobj1`) so as to establish the scope chain.
34. It creates a property, `alpha`, on `callback#varobj1`
35. It starts step-by-step execution of `callback`'s code
36. You know what happens next. It looks up various symbols and calls various functions:

    - Looks up `newSection`, which it doesn't find on `callback#varobj1` and so looks at the next link, `foo#varobj1`. Not finding it there, it looks at the next link, which is the global object, and finds it.
    - Looks up `alpha`, which it finds on the topmost variable object, `callback#varobj1`
    - Looks up `beta`, which it doesn't find until it gets down to the global object
    - Looks up `gamma`, which it finds only one link down the scope chain on `foo#varobj1`
37. The interpreter returns from the call to `callback`
38. Almost certainly, there in its event queue there's a message from the browser waiting for it, telling it to call the second `callback` function, which we created in our second call to `foo`.
39. So it does it all again. This time, the variable object for the call to `callback` gets a reference to `foo#varobj2` because that's what's stored on this particular `callback` function object. So (amongst other things) it sees the `gamma` argument we passed to the second call, rather than the first one.
40. Since the browser has now released its references to the two `callback` function objects, they and the objects they refer to (including `foo#varobj1`, `foo#varobj2`, and anything their properties point to, like `gamma`'s strings) are all eligible for garbage collection.

***Whew*** That was fun, eh?

One final point about the above: Note how JavaScript scope is determined *entirely* by the nesting of the functions in the source code; this is called "lexical scoping." E.g., the call stack doesn't matter for variable resolution (except in terms of when functions get *created*, because they get a reference to the variable object in scope when they were created), just the nesting in the source code. Consider ([live copy](http://jsbin.com/ijinof/2)):

```
var alpha = "I'm window.alpha";

function foo() {
    var alpha = "I'm alpha in the variable object for the call to `foo`";

    bar();
}

function bar() {

    display("alpha = " + alpha);
}

foo();
```

What ends up getting output for `alpha`? Right! `"I'm window.alpha"`. The `alpha` we define in `foo` has no effect whatsoever on `bar`, even though we called `bar` from `foo`. Let's quickly walk through:

1. Set up global execution context etc. etc.
2. Create properties for the `var`s and declared functions.
3. Assign `alpha` its value.
4. Create the `foo` function object, give it a reference to the current variable object (which is the global object), put it on the `foo` property.
5. Create the `bar` function object, give it a reference to the current variable object (which is the global object), put it on the `bar` property.
6. Call `foo` by creating an execution context and variable object. The variable object, `foo#varobj1`, gets a copy of `foo`'s reference to its parent variable object, which is of course the global object.
7. Start step-by-step execution of `foo`'s code.
8. Look up the free variable `bar`, which it finds on the global object.
9. Create an execution context for the call to `bar` and its associated variable object `bar#varobj1`. Assign `bar#varobj1` a copy of `bar`'s reference to its parent variable object, which is of course the global object.
10. Start step-by-step execution of `bar`'s code.
11. Look up the free variable `alpha`:

    - First it looks on `bar#varobj1`, but there's no property with that name there
    - So it looks at the next link, which is the link it got from `bar`, which is the global object. So it finds the global `alpha`

Note how `foo#varobj1` isn't linked at all to `bar`'s variable object. And that's good, because we'd all go nuts if what was in scope was defined by how and from where a function was called. :-) Once you understand that it's linked to function *creation*, which is dictated by the nesting of the source code, it gets a *lot* easier to understand.

And that's why what's in scope for `bar` is determined entirely by where `bar` is in the source code, not how it got called at runtime.

It's not surprising that initially you were wondering about the relationship between `this` and variable resolution, because the global object (`window`) serves two *unrelated* purposes in JavaScript: 1. It's the default `this` value if a function isn't called in a way that sets a different one (and at global scope), and 2. It's the global variable object. These are unrelated aspects of what the interpreter uses with the global object for, which can be confusing, because when `this` === `window`, it seems like variable resolution relates in some way to `this`, but it doesn't. As soon as you start using something else for `this`, `this` and variable resolution are completely disconnected from one another.

Comment: I just want to check my understanding:  In any scope (global or function) there are always 2 objects: a “this” object (what is that called?) and a “variable object”.  In the global scope, these 2 objects are the same.  In a function’s scope, they are different, and the “variable object” is not accessible.  Is that correct?

Comment: @zod: I've updated the answer to address that comment. Hope this helps,

Comment: @zod: And crazy man that I am, I just added some detailed code walkthroughs to really lay it out. Must blog this.

Answer (score 0):

You have some examples in this fiddle :

```
var x = 42;

function alertXs() {
    this.x = 'not 42'; // this = window
    var x = '42 not'; // local x

    alert('window.x = ' + window.x); // 'not 42'
    alert('this.x = ' + this.x);     // 'not 42'
    alert('x = ' + x);               // '42 not'

}

alertXs();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Christophe/Pgk73/

Sometimes, creating tiny fiddles helps to understand...

But you are aware with local and public variable as you explain that very well...

Comment: Live links are a great *adjunct* to an answer, but always post the relevant code *in the answer* as well. Two reasons. 1. People shouldn't have to follow a link to see what you're saying. 2. StackOverflow is meant to be a resource not just for this questioner now, but for others having a similar issue in the future. External links can get moved, modified, deleted, etc. By making sure the relevant code is in the answer, we ensure that the answer remains useful for a reasonable period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of properties and constructors is fine; the concepts you're missing are 'scopes' and 'closures'.  This is where `var` comes into play.

Try reading [Robert Nyman's explanation](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/)